# Definite integral $\int_0^1\Bigl| e^x-a\Bigl|dx, a>0$ and its smallest value

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

**How can I evaluate the smallest value of** $I_{(a)}=\int_0^1\Bigl| e^x-a\Bigl|dx, a>0$ and express it like this: $\Bigl(\sqrt{e}-E\Bigl)^F$, where **the smallest value of I(a) is took at** $a=e^{\frac{G}{H}}$**?**

(In other words I'm looking for E,F,G and H).

I've already know that the answers are:

E=1, F=2,G=1 and H=2, but I have no idea how to get to this solution.
Could someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guide:

Note that $e^x$ is an increasing function.

$e^0=1$ and $e^1 = e$.

$a$ must be a value between $1$ and $e$. Let $e^{t}=a$, $0 < t< 1$.

\begin{align}\int_0^1 |e^x-a|\, dx &= \int_0^{t}e^t-e^x\, dx + \int_{t}^1e^x-e^t\, dx \\
&= te^t - \int_0^t e^x \, dx  + \int_t^1 e^x \, dx - e^t(1-t)\end{align}

Now, you can use differentiation to find the turning point.